# Epson receipt printer slow on Linux

Tags: linux, printing

I am trying to set up a POS station for web-based software. The receipt printer, an 
Epson TM-T88V, is slow using Epson's own drivers and prescribed installation method.
To clarify, it is slower than on Windows. It spits out a blank header, pauses for a 
few seconds then prints the rest of the receipt. Formatting of receipt is fine, speed
is only issue.

OS: Ubuntu 11.10 ( same results in 11.04 )

It uses the rastertotmt driver provided by Epson, as mentioned above.

Here's the printers.conf:

```
<DefaultPrinter Epson-TM-T88V>
UUID urn:uuid:4fab29dd-edb0-36fb-4eb1-3aa2cf19975b
Info Epson TM-T88V
Location POS-station
MakeModel EPSON TM-T88V (rastertotmt)
DeviceURI epsontm:/ESDPRT001
State Idle
StateTime 1320176819
Type 36868
Accepting Yes
Shared Yes
JobSheets none none
QuotaPeriod 0
PageLimit 0
KLimit 0
OpPolicy default
ErrorPolicy retry-job
</Printer>
```

Here's some dmesg output just post-installation:

```
[69956.715068] audit_printk_skb: 15 callbacks suppressed
[69956.715074] type=1400 audit(1320175158.146:23): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=5690 comm="apparmor_parser"
[69956.715929] type=1400 audit(1320175158.146:24): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=5690 comm="apparmor_parser"
[70030.281708] parport0: ppdev0 forgot to release port
[70670.262444] parport0: ppdev0 forgot to release port
[70824.008066] usb 4-1: USB disconnect, device number 5
[70857.790342] type=1400 audit(1320176059.223:25): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/lib/cups/backend/cups-pdf" pid=6093 comm="apparmor_parser"
[70857.791034] type=1400 audit(1320176059.223:26): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_replace" name="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=6093 comm="apparmor_parser"
[70915.125238] parport0: ppdev0 forgot to release port
[71531.048040] usb 4-1: new full speed USB device number 6 using uhci_hcd
```

I do not see anything in CUP'S error_log worthy of mention.

Thanks in advance for any advice you may have!

Bubnoff

** **UPDATE** **

For those traveling down this same road:
The Star TSP100 runs flawlessly, beautifully and fast on Linux. Cheaper too.
The installation is simpler as well.

My theory is that Epson's "Epuras" service that it installs is to blame for the 
slower speeds. The Star installs only the raster binaries and drivers -- a total
of three files, then runs like a dream -- **WITHOUT** installing a crappy background
service. The Epson installs essentially the same files ---- then insists on dumping
the epuras service on your system. I am going to experiment with installing the Epson
without Epuras and see how it runs. I don't believe it's necessary as it's pretty much
the same printer. Will report back on how it goes.

Here's some output illustrating new and needless blubber added by the Epson installer:

```
 ps aux | grep epura
```

```
root       896  0.0  0.1  46296  1016 ?        Ssl  Nov01   0:25 /usr/sbin/epurasd
root       919  0.0  0.0   4508   708 ?        Ss   Nov01   0:00 /usr/sbin/epuraslogd
```

Two new services running as root on my system! No such crap needed by the Star printer.
Did I actually pay more to get this crappy service added?

**UPDATE 2**

The newest drivers from Epson fix this issue -- they print like the wind on Debian 6.04 "Squeeze". So either Stars or Epsons --- good. Get the newest drivers available from the website and toss the CD.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer ( Yes, I'm answering my own question ):

Don't use an Epson. Save the money and headaches and go with a Star.

In my tests on Mac, Linux and Windows, it's an easy install, runs fast
and easy to deploy since there's no crappy background services to install.
What do those crappy Epson services do anyway? An entire service just to log
the errors of the other service?

Comment: Newest drivers on Epson website fix the speed/pause issue. Toss the CD and head straight for the website.